# Как логировать вход пользователя в сеть в discord.py?

Tags: python

Как логировать вход пользователя в сеть в discord.py?
Что бы к примеру выводить в консоль его ник#тег

Answer (score 0):

Как я правильно понял чтобы отображался ник создателя программы.
В консоли

```
print("discord#1234")
```

а в tkinter

```
Label(text="discord#1234", fg="black", bg="white").place(x=1, y=40)
```

а готовый код с текстом

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My discord")

Label(text="discord#1234", fg="black", bg="white").place(x=1, y=40)

window.mainloop()
```